# Basic Org-mode: links handling - explanation of `C-c l` (manual unclear)

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

[The compact org-mode guide](https://orgmode.org/guide/Handling-links.html) says

```
C-c l

Store a link to the current location. This is a global command   
(you must create the key binding yourself) which can be used  
in any buffer to create a link. The link will be stored   
for later insertion into an Org buffer (see below).`
```

**Q1.**

Clearly, I am not able to use the command `C-c l`, even though the org-mode is active.
Is this what they meant when the manual says: **you must create the key binding yourself**?

How can I do it?

**Q2.**

By the word **global** did they mean that we can use it in any other file to store the position and paste it in any other file *or* something else?

**Q3.**

What buffer is used to store this position? Can I access/see its contents without pasting the link using `C-c C-l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the key binding see the `Introduction > Activation` section, where amongst other thing is suggests

```
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
```

This is to be place in you `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` file.  To test it, you can paste the code in to the `*scratch*` buffer and use `C-x C-e` when the cursor is at the end of the expression.

Yes, `global` here means you can use it any buffer in Emacs.  Its exact behaviour depends on the type of buffer you are in.  Full details are in the full org manual.

The links are saved in the variable `org-stored-links`.  `C-h v org-stored-links` will show documentation and its current value.  The format is not so user friendly; instead you can use `C-c C-l` which pops-up a list of known links and then abort the paste operation with `C-g`.